# Did the interface change, did I lose a privilege, or is everything just slightly wonky?

Tags: support, closing-questions, answers, votes

I've just noticed that I no longer seem to have the ability to recommend some posts for closure (which I noticed because I wanted to do something with a link only post – I eventually took the available options of commenting and flagging).

The system has been a bit wonky the last couple of days, so I wouldn't be surprised if it's that – but I wonder perhaps: did I fail some review and not notice?

Not sure if bug or just bug in user.

Edit: added the "bug" tag as suggested, as the behavior seems to persist. It's still not clear whether this is a real issue or just faulty memory/understanding.

---

An example (from a few hours ago) where I'd normally think I'd see a close option:

> [image]

The [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112613/paired-t-test-with-subsamples-in-r) has a close option for me, but the answer doesn't.

I went with flagging it (which helps me I guess, because it gets me closer to a Marshal badge, but most of these sort of things I'd try to deal with another way if I can).

I notice some of my rep totals are still inconsistent across different displays (connected with the issues from the last few days), so it may all be connected to that, perhaps.

---

Edit: apparently just a bug in the user. I've removed the `bug` tag and cropped the image to remove the comment field.

Comment: I can recommend closure. You can only recommend deleting a Q after it's been closed for some period of time, & an answer if it has 3+ downvotes, so I can't test that.

Comment: @gung Thanks. It was odd - usually I have the ability to at least recommend closure, but yesterday there were a lot of posts (but not all of them, which was even odder to my eyes) where there was no 'close' option. [I've removed the reference to deletion since it's a distraction from the main issue.]

Comment: Arg, I tried to comment in the comment field in the jpeg. At any rate... @Glen_b, what you show is an *answer*; answers never have a close option--only questions do. You *flag* answers & *close* Q's (if rep>3k, or flag if <3k; you can also flag to notify the moderators of something when rep>3k). I wonder if there's a problem or a confusion.

Comment: @gung After I posted, I wondered if someone might do that. Sorry, I should have cut that bit off. Interesting - apparently it's just that I've misremembered the options I've had. It sounds like your comment is actually a complete answer, and I'm just an idiot (though I have been sick, and fuzzy-headed the last few days, so that might explain why I suddenly thought I used to have an option I never actually had).

Comment: @NickStauner (I guess that won't notify you, but anyway) -- why the `votes` tag?

Comment: It's debatable. Currently [meta-tag:vote-to-close] is synonymized with [meta-tag:votes], and should also cover delete votes, which seems to have been what you were looking for...but I tend to be liberal in tagging things, and people who review my edits (on other sites where I have to suggest them) often remove one or two. I don't get it, but I acknowledge my bias :)

Comment: @Nick Ah. That makes sense to me now. vote-to-close -> votes ... got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot *close* answers.  Answers can only be flagged.  (Actually, if an answer has a score <-1 and your reputation is >20k, you can vote to [delete](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), but that's a different story.)  Only questions can be closed (this assumes your [reputation is >3k](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions), if it's less you flag).  It might be confusing that you can flag both questions and answers, but only close questions, but flagging questions gives different options.  When your reputation is >3k, mostly flagging questions is just about leaving a note for the moderators.

Comment: Thanks. It may be this "*Actually, if an answer has a score <-1 and your reputation is >20k, you can vote to delete, but that's a different story*" that led to my initial confusion (see first version in edit history) about having seen one of either a close or delete option on both.